# I agree to the terms and conditions on this website

Tags: contract-law, international, terms-of-service

In the US we have the concept of a digital signature being anything that two parties agree to being a "signature".  We are just now internationalizing our website and I'm wondering just how valid our "I agree to the terms and conditions on this website" really is for people from other countries.  We require that a user click a checkbox agreeing before they create an account, buy things etc.  They have to agree, or they can't do things, but is that agreement actually binding in all the places where there is internet service?

Right now we have a Chinese Translation, but they want to add 20+ other languages.  How binding is that checkbox on people from other countries?

We are in a UK territory and are not a US company.

I remember all the hullabaloo about how this digital signature law was a "landmark decision" that blah blah blah.  If it really was something special, wouldn't other countries have had to agree to something similar or pass similar legislation?  (yes, I'm that old)

Comment: It's as binding there as it is binding there. Without giving a jurisdiction we can't just list all of the potentially thousands of jurisdictions that might apply and hope we got the ones you're looking at.

Comment: Often translations say "in case of disputes, [native lang of devs] version is binding. But you still have jurisdictional differences.

Comment: There are two completely different questions here, one about multiple version of an agreement, and one about multiple jurisdictions (i.e. does some country have special requirements for click-wrap agreements). You should really split this into two questions.

Comment: I only have one question that I see.  Multiple versions isn't the question, it's whether the digital signature (in the form a checkbox) and a submit button actually makes the agreement binding in other countries.